# How do you make a 'sticky' cluetip that opens on click, close on a click outside of the tip itself?

Tags: jquery, cluetip

I have a cluetip that is set to sticky and opens when one clicks a link.  I also set a close button on the cluetip and all of that works great.  I want to close the cluetip if someone clicks outside of the cluetip in addition to the current close button.  I am looking for the hover out solution, just a close on click outside of the cluetip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the FAQ, there is an API method to let you trigger a close:

> New as of clueTip 1.0.3: How do I programmatically close (hide) a clueTip?
> If you want to trigger a clueTip to close, based on some other interaction, you can use the following code: `$(document).trigger('hideCluetip');`

So I think you could do something like this:

```
$('#myCluetip').cluetip({
  onShow: function() {
    $(document).one('mousedown',function() {
      $(document).trigger('hideCluetip');
    })
  });
});
```

This works by binding a one-time event handler for the mousedown event to the document body, which then triggers the event that the Cluetip folks say will hide open Cluetips. Using the one-time event handler means that you're not sending the hideCluetip trigger every single time somebody clicks on something.

Comment: I ended up taking this concept of using hideClueTip but bound and unbound the events for mouseup via the onShow and onHide hooks depending if the click was in the tip or not (i decided to close the tip when click outside of tip).

Comment: @mornos - can you post your solution ?

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I did it:

```
    onShow: function() {
        // close cluetip when users click outside of it
        $(document).click(function(e) {
            var isInClueTip = $(e.target).closest('#cluetip');
            if (isInClueTip.length === 0) {
                $('.cluetip-default').hide();
            }
        })
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

Stony's solution did not work for me.

I used @Gary Green's solution, and it works ok - but that's still not the exact "close on mouseout/hoverout" solution I wanted.

Finally, I figured out that Cluetip itself provides a way to do this.

Just set the value "mouseOutClose: false" , like this:

```
$("#myForm :input").cluetip(
    {
        sticky: true, 
        closePosition: 'title', 
        arrows: true,
        mouseOutClose: true
    }
);
```

Comment: just to add, you need to add sticky option for the mouseOutClose to work.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see your code but anyway you can do something along these lines;

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).hasClass('cluetip'))
    {
      // Close the cluetip here.  
    }
});
```